# SchemaExport using custom types

Tags: hibernate, sap-ase, schemaexport, custom-type

I'd like to use org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport from hibernate-core 4.1.4 to generate/export a Sybase ASE 15.5 schema where specific columns should be created as UNIVARCHAR instead of the regular VARCHAR data type. How do I do that? My preferred way is to use annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By giving SQL fragment as a value of  [columnDefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition%28%29) attribute in Column annotation.

For example:

```
@Column(name="columnName", columnDefinition="univarchar(50)")
```